# Double way API?

Tags: api, web-services, service, architecture, microservices

For the moment, all my customers are in the same db, same domain etc… on my majestic monolith on `https://www.mystartup.com`.

Let’s say I want to deploy an instance of my rails app for one big customer. And let’s say I may deploy other instances of this rails app in the future.

The thing is that I am fetching and computing some heavy data, and I want to do it once instead of in all the instances. So I guess I should do them in `https://secret-api.mystartup.com`, and each of the instance should make requests to it with secret access token.

But my issue is this one : is there a way for `https://secret-api.mystartup.com` to trigger some calls to each of the domains, when needed? Is this what we call “webhooks”? or is there some double-way-api concept that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Yes, a request from an API to one or more of its client applications would be considered a webhook.

Comment: Look into tools like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq). In addition to providing asynchronous processing, they can guarantee that jobs are only processed once.

Answer (score 0):

One question you need to answer is that what if this secret-api server need to be restarted ! You loose all that heavy lifting computation..

Another problem with above solution is that it is going against micro-services architecture in a way.. because you are having a single server for secret-api.. What if this goes down; then your whole system goes down... With micro-services; for high availability you should always have multiple servers for same api.

For such scenarios; when there is heavy lifting to be done, one solution could be that have an in-memory layer in between something like memcached or redis..keep your solutions in this in-meory server and NOT inside a cache maintained inside your secret-api server.. This solution will solve both above mentioned problems.